# disable bold font and coloring in grep

Tags: grep

I want to use the output of command:

`fdisk -l | grep -i "/dev"`

in my bash script. 
[image: current output of command]

But the problem is that it **bold** and highlight/color the matched output. I don't want that. I **only** want to print the lines that matched the criteria.

Comment: You should `unalias grep` or if that's not enough, use `grep --color=never`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your shell has probably a defined alias. `alias grep='grep --color=auto'` is rather common in `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc`. You can remove the alias or replace it with

```
grep --color=never
```

You can of course use `grep --color=never` manually instead when you don't want colors, as it expands to `grep --color=auto --color=never` and the latter option overrules the former.

See `grep --help`, `man grep` or `info "(grep)General Output Control"` for more information.